# Como criar e ler um XML com Python?

Tags: python, xml

Como criar e ler um XML com o componente `DOM` em Python?

E como ler um XML com o componente `cElementTree` do Python?

Comment: Tem algum problema específico que você esteja tendo? O que você já conseguiu fazer? Precisamos de perguntas objetivas para fornecer respostas mais precisas e duradouras.

Answer (score 9):

O Python tem duas maneiras *built-in* de lidar com arquivos XML: o [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) e o [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html). Além disso, existem bibliotecas externas que podem simplificar bastante o trabalho de lidar com XML, como o [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), o [`pyquery`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) e o [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) (além de implementações nativas com API compatível, como o [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)). Ou seja, opção não falta, a questão é saber qual delas se encaixa melhor nas suas necessidades.

## ElementTree

Segundo a documentação, o `ElementTree` é "recomendado para quem não tem experiência prévia trabalhando com o DOM". Ele representa um arquivo XML e seus elementos em objetos Python com uma API própria, e permite modificá-los e convertê-los de volta ao formato XML. Também dá suporte a um subconjunto de [XPath](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) - que você pode usar nas consultas.

Nota: O `cElementTree` que você mencionou na pergunta é simplesmente uma implementação em C da API `ElementTree` (ou seja, após instalado, o uso é igual).

**Prós:** simples e "pitônico" de usar, suporte a XPath.
**Contras:** nenhum.
**Exemplo:**

```python
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()

>>> [(x.tag, x.attrib) for x in root] # Lista os elementos filhos: nome e atributos
[('country', {'name':'Liechtenstein'}), (...), (...)]

>>> root[0][8].text # Acessa um sub-elemento por índice, obtém seu texto
'2008'

>>> [x.attrib for x in root.iter('neighbor')] # Lista elementos descendentes: atributos
[{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}, {...}, {...}, ...]

>>> atualizar = root.iter['rank'][0]
>>> atualizar.text = "1"
>>> atualizar.set('updated', 'yes')
>>> root.write('output.xml')

>>> a = ET.Element('a')
>>> b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
>>> c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
>>> d = ET.SubElement(c, 'd')
>>> ET.dump(a)
"<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>"
```

## minidom

Implementação mínima do DOM, com API similar a de outras linguagens, como JavaScript. Para quem já tem familiaridade com a manipulação do DOM em JavaScript puro (i.e. sem bibliotecas externas), e quer manipular XML em Python usando um código semelhante.

**Prós:** API semelhante à do JavaScript.
**Contras:** bastante verboso.
**Exemplo:** Ver a [resposta do @utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3614/215).

## lxml

*Binding* "pitônico" para as bibliotecas C [`libxml2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2) e [`libxslt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxslt). Eficiente e completo (*feature rich*), e com uma API simples e **compatível** com a `ElementTree`.

**Prós:** performance.
**Contras:** nenhum.
**Exemplo:** Em sua maioria, idêntico ao `ElementTree` (só muda o `import xml...` para `import lxml...`).

## BeautifulSoup

Seu principal uso é pra interpretar/manipular HTML, mas suporta XML também. Sua principal característica é ser bastante robusto quando seus arquivos de entrada não estão necessariamente bem formatados.

**Prós:** robustez.
**Contras:** um pouco mais verboso ao modificar/criar.
**Exemplo:**

```python
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> root = BeautifulSoup(open('country_data.xml'))

>>> [(x.name, x.attrs) for x in root.children] # Lista os elementos filhos: nome e atributos
[('country', {'name':'Liechtenstein'}), (...), (...)]

>>> root.contents[0].contents[7].string # Acessa um sub-elemento por índice, obtém seu texto
'2008'

>>> [x.attrs for x in root.find_all('neighbor')] # Lista elementos descendentes: atributos
[{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}, {...}, {...}, ...]

>>> atualizar = root.rank # "atalho" para root.find_all('rank')[0]
>>> atualizar.string = "1"
>>> with open('output.xml') as f:
...     f.write(unicode(root))

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup
>>> a = soup("<a />")
>>> a.append(soup.new_tag("b"))
>>> c = soup.new_tag("c")
>>> a.append(c)
>>> c.append(soup.new_tag("d"))
>>> str(soup)
"<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>"
```

## pyquery

Biblioteca que tenta "mimicar" o [jQuery](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) num ambiente Python. Para quem já tem familiaridade com o uso dessa framework e quer manipular XML em Python usando um código semelhante. Depende do `lxml`.

**Prós:** [jQuery!!!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/177950)
**Contras:** documentação fraca [no que se refere a casos não cobertos, onde o *fallback* fica pro lxml].
**Exemplo:**

```python
>>> from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
>>> root = pq(filename='country_data.xml')

>>> root.children().map(lambda x: (x.tag, x.attrib)) # Lista os elementos filhos: nome e atributos
[('country', {'name':'Liechtenstein'}), (...), (...)]

>>> root.children(":eq(0)").children(":eq(7)").text() # Acessa um sub-elemento por índice, obtém seu texto
'2008'

>>> root.find('neighbor').map(lambda x: x.attrib) # Lista elementos descendentes: atributos

>>> atualizar = root.find('rank:eq(0)').text('1')
>>> with open('output.xml') as f:
...     f.write(unicode(root))

>>> print pq('a')\
...   .append('b')\
...   .append(pq('c').append('d'))
"<a><b /><c><d /></c></a>"
```

## xmltodict

Converte um arquivo XML em um `dict` simples, que pode ser acessado e manipulado simplesmente através das chaves e valores. Também pode ser convertido de volta num XML. Oferece suporte para namespaces, através de um parâmetro extra ao fazer o *parse*.

**Prós:** API super simples e homogênea em suas operações.
**Contras:** documentação fraca.
**Exemplo:** Ver a [resposta do @avelino](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3703/215).

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Fiz a seguinte implementação no Python 3.3 para ler um XML:

```python
from xml.dom import minidom

xml ="""<raiz>
    <itens>
        <item name="item1">Item 1</item>
        <item name="item2">Item 2</item>
        <item name="item3">Item 3</item>
    </itens>
</raiz> 
"""

#ler do arquivo
#xmldoc = minidom.parse('itens.xml')

#ler da string
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml)

itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item') 
print('Quantidade de itens:', len(itemlist))
for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['name'].value, ' =', s.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

E para criar um XML:

```python
#cria documento
doc = minidom.Document()

#cria raiz e adicionar no documento
raiz = doc.createElement('raiz')
doc.appendChild(doc.createElement('raiz'))

#cria itens e adiciona na raiz
itens = doc.createElement('itens')
raiz.appendChild(itens)

#cria itens e textos
for i in range(3):
    item = doc.createElement('item')
    item.setAttribute('name', 'item' + str(i+1))
    itens.appendChild(item)
    item.appendChild( doc.createTextNode('Item ' + str(i + 1)))

#xmldoc = minidom.Document()
print(raiz.toprettyxml())
```

Só é preciso notar que a documentação do minidom aconselha a não usá-lo em caso de processamento de XML de fontes não confiáveis, devido a [algumas vulnerabilidades](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities).

---

Quanto ao [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm), não o tenho instalado para testar, mas o uso parece bem direto conforme o exemplo da documentação:

import cElementTree

```python
for event, elem in cElementTree.iterparse(file):
    if elem.tag == "record":
        ... process record element ...
        elem.clear()
```

Basicamente:

- `cElementTree.iterparse(file)` lê o arquivo
- o loop é invocada para cada evento de tag
- o `if` testa para ver se o evento foi causado por uma determinada tag, permitindo processá-la conforme necessário.

Existem vários exemplos [aqui](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm).

Comment: O `cElementTree` parece ser simplesmente uma implementação em C da API [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree), ou seja: o uso deve ser exatamente o mesmo (ou estou enganado?). Fiz [um comparativo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3709/215) das principais bibliotecas suportadas pelo Python.

Comment: @mgibsonbr É exatamente isso. E outra coisa que eu não havia reparado é que parece que essa implementação já vem com o Python: "*cElementTree is included with Python 2.5 and later, as xml.etree.cElementTree.*".

Comment: @mgibsonbr Só não sei se isso continua igual no Python 3. Ainda estou meio perdido com essas diferenças entre a versão 2 e 3. Algumas documentações simplesmente não fazem menção disso ou estão desatualizadas. Mas tudo pode ser ignorância minha, pois comecei a aprender Python há apenas 3 semanas... :)

Comment: Eu acredito que o "CPython", sempre que define uma API "genérica" e precisa dar uma implementação concreta, usa uma implementação em C. Por isso não creio que o Python 3 tenha "regredido" nesse ponto... Mas é só um palpite, na realidade nunca nem experimentei o Python 3...

Answer (score 3):

Existe varias forma de ler XML com Python, uma das formas mais simples é o **XMLtoDict**, ele converte a estrutura do XML para um dict (dicionario Python):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict

Veja um exemplo:

````
```python
>>> doc = xmltodict.parse("""
... <mydocument has="an attribute">
...   <and>
...     <many>elements</many>
...     <many>more elements</many>
...   </and>
...   <plus a="complex">
...     element as well
...   </plus>
... </mydocument>
... """)
>>>
>>> doc['mydocument']['@has']
u'an attribute'
>>> doc['mydocument']['and']['many']
[u'elements', u'more elements']
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['@a']
u'complex'
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['#text']
u'element as well'
````