# Lendo um arquivo XML e imprimindo campos específicos usando a linguagem Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho o seguinte arquivo XML (na verdade é um pedaço apenas do arquivo):

```
<!DOCTYPE sysstat PUBLIC "DTD v2.19 sysstat //EN"
        "http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/sysstat-2.19.dtd">
        <sysstat>
            <sysdata-version>2.19</sysdata-version>
            <host nodename="ServerLabDoS">
                <sysname>Linux</sysname>
                <release>3.16.0-4-686-pae</release>
                <machine>i686</machine>
                <number-of-cpus>1</number-of-cpus>
                <file-date>2017-04-10</file-date>
                <file-utc-time>10:39:04</file-utc-time>
                <statistics>
                    <timestamp date="2017-04-10" time="07:50:12" utc="0" interval="119">
                        <memory per="second" unit="kB">
                            <memfree>1140168</memfree>
                            <memused>131440</memused>
                            <memused-percent>10.34</memused-percent>
                            <buffers>10928</buffers>
                            <cached>51716</cached>
                            <commit>510544</commit>
                            <commit-percent>28.87</commit-percent>
                            <active>56880</active>
                            <inactive>29832</inactive>
                            <dirty>44</dirty>
                        </memory>
                        <network per="second">
                            <net-dev iface="lo" rxpck="0.00" txpck="0.00" rxkB="0.00" txkB="0.00" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                            <net-dev iface="eth0" rxpck="12.58" txpck="11.50" rxkB="11.95" txkB="0.85" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                        </network>
                    </timestamp>
                    <timestamp date="2017-04-10" time="07:52:01" utc="0" interval="107">
                        <memory per="second" unit="kB">
                            <memfree>1140444</memfree>
                            <memused>131164</memused>
                            <memused-percent>10.31</memused-percent>
                            <buffers>11288</buffers>
                            <cached>51932</cached>
                            <commit>509260</commit>
                            <commit-percent>28.80</commit-percent>
                            <active>57024</active>
                            <inactive>29840</inactive>
                            <dirty>28</dirty>
                        </memory>
                        <network per="second">
                            <net-dev iface="lo" rxpck="0.00" txpck="0.00" rxkB="0.00" txkB="0.00" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                            <net-dev iface="eth0" rxpck="13.89" txpck="12.69" rxkB="13.71" txkB="0.93" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                        </network>
                    </timestamp>
                    <timestamp date="2017-04-10" time="07:54:01" utc="0" interval="119">
                        <memory per="second" unit="kB">
                            <memfree>1139716</memfree>
                            <memused>131892</memused>
                            <memused-percent>10.37</memused-percent>
                            <buffers>11664</buffers>
                            <cached>52192</cached>
                            <commit>509148</commit>
                            <commit-percent>28.79</commit-percent>
                            <active>57384</active>
                            <inactive>29948</inactive>
                            <dirty>76</dirty>
                        </memory>
                        <network per="second">
                            <net-dev iface="lo" rxpck="0.00" txpck="0.00" rxkB="0.00" txkB="0.00" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                            <net-dev iface="eth0" rxpck="13.35" txpck="12.40" rxkB="13.68" txkB="0.91" rxcmp="0.00" txcmp="0.00" rxmcst="0.00" ifutil-percent="0.00"/>
                        </network>
                    </timestamp>
</statistics>
        </host>
    </sysstat>
```

Meu objetivo é dado um intervalo de timestamp, como por exemplo, entre `date="2017-04-10" time="07:50:12"` e `date="2017-04-10" time="07:52:01"`, imprimir `memused` e `rxpck` usando Python.

Comecei o código:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("arq.xml")

# doc.getElementsByTagName returns NodeList
timestamp = doc.getElementsByTagName("timestamp")[0]
print(timestamp.firstChild.data)
```

Mas não saio disso. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Vamos supor que no XML tivesse um dia com diversos horários diferentes.O que eu queria era imprimir esses valores para todos os horários contidos no arquivo XML.

Exemplo de um XML assim: https://ufile.io/4yd3x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa definir os limiares de data que o seu script tem que trabalhar. Para isso você deve usar a biblioteca `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

begin = datetime(2017, 4, 10, 7, 50, 12)
end = datetime(2017, 4, 10, 7, 52, 1)
```

Depois você tem que iterar sobre todas as *tags* `timestamp`, obter as respectivas data e hora e filtrar as que não estiverem no *range* definido. Obtenha os atributos `date` e `time` com o método `getAttribute()` e faça a interpretação da *strings* com o `datetime.strptime()`:

```
for timestamp in doc.getElementsByTagName('timestamp'):
    date = timestamp.getAttribute('date')
    time = timestamp.getAttribute('time')
    dt = datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if dt < begin or dt >= end:
        continue
```

Pronto, agora basta obter o conteúdo da *tag* `memused`, iterar sobre todas as interfaces de rede (*tags* `net-dev`) e obter os atributos desejados (`rxpck` e talvez `iface`):

```
memused = timestamp.getElementsByTagName('memused')[0].firstChild.data
for netdev in timestamp.getElementsByTagName('net-dev'):
    iface = netdev.getAttribute('iface')
    rxpck = netdev.getAttribute('rxpck')
    print 'date:%s time:%s memused:%s iface:%s rxpck:%s' % (date, time, memused, iface, rxpck)
```

Segue abaixo o código completo para facilitar o teste:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from xml.dom import minidom
from datetime import datetime

doc = minidom.parse('arq.xml')

begin = datetime(2017, 4, 10, 7, 50, 12)
end = datetime(2017, 4, 10, 7, 52, 1)

for timestamp in doc.getElementsByTagName('timestamp'):
    date = timestamp.getAttribute('date')
    time = timestamp.getAttribute('time')
    dt = datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (date, time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if dt < begin or dt >= end:
        continue
    memused = timestamp.getElementsByTagName('memused')[0].firstChild.data
    for netdev in timestamp.getElementsByTagName('net-dev'):
        iface = netdev.getAttribute('iface')
        rxpck = netdev.getAttribute('rxpck')
        print 'date:%s time:%s memused:%s iface:%s rxpck:%s' % (date, time, memused, iface, rxpck)
```

Para maiores informações sobre como manipular arquivos XML em Python recomendo ler o [manual do `minidom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) (em inglês apenas, infelizmente) ou as respostas para [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3561/como-criar-e-ler-um-xml-com-python).

Comment: se além de imprimir, quisesse salvar os valores organizadamente em arquivo texto, seria dificil?

Comment: Não, basta usar as funções `open` e `write`: `open('arquivo.txt', 'a').write(string)`. Caso não entenda como encaixar no código sugiro procurar por exemplos no StackOverflow ou fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Acho que eu formulei mal a questao:
vamos supor que no XML tivesse um dia com  diversos horários.O que eu queria era imprimir esses valores para todos os horários contidos no arquivo.

Comment: seria para imprimir todos os valores para cada horário existente!

Comment: exemplo de um XML assim: https://ufile.io/4yd3x

Comment: Mas isso ele faz, basta configurar as variáveis `begin` e `end` com os valores corretos. Sugiro atribuir a primeira hora do dia à variável `begin` e a última hora à `end`. Exemplo: `begin = datetime(2017, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0)` e `end = datetime(2017, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: tentei modificar aqui mas ele só imprimiu dois valores...

Comment: Com certeza você não modificou corretamente. Basta substituir as duas linhas onde tem `begin =` e `end =`.

Comment: desculpe a minha ignorância! Você tem razao. O script funciona! Você poderia deixar na sua resposta algum link de referencia sobre XML com python?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63301/discussion-between-fernando-silveira-and-ed-s).